# Ruby on Rails: Faster way to navigate through YAML files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am just localizing a Rails app for the first time and I wonder if there's a shorter way to say this:

```
flash[:success] = t('.views.person.flash_messages.person_was_successfully_updated')
```

This is an excerpt of my `de.yml` file:

```
de: 
  views:
    person:
      flash_messages:
        person_was_successfully_updated: "Person aktualisiert."
```

I would *looove* to say something like this:

```
flash[:success] = t('person_was_successfully_updated')
```

But Rails is giving me an error, when I try to do so.

I don't understand why because `person_was_successfully_updated` is absolutely unique in my `.yml` file and I don't see the need for typing in the entire path every time. This is not very *DRY* either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I would looove to say something like this*

If you want to call `person_was_successfully_updated` directly then you should put that in first level. i.e., under **de:**..

*But Rails is giving me an error, when I try to do so.*

Yes it will definitely give error because there is no `person_was_successfully_updated` in root level.

For more info. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html